# Casperjs visible() returns true while jquery is(':visible') returns false for the same selector

Tags: javascript, visibility, casperjs

`casper.visible('#percent_med_pickup');` returns true, while the following code with the same selector returns false:

```
casper.evaluate(function(){

return $('#percent_med_pickup').is(':visible');
});
```

Aren't both the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are very different.

CasperJS ([source](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/1.1-beta3/modules/clientutils.js#L156-L171)):

```
this.elementVisible = function elementVisible(elem) {
    var style;
    try {
        style = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    var hidden = style.visibility === 'hidden' || style.display === 'none';
    if (hidden) {
        return false;
    }
    if (style.display === "inline" || style.display === "inline-block") {
        return true;
    }
    return elem.clientHeight > 0 && elem.clientWidth > 0;
};
```

jQuery ([source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js)):

```
jQuery.expr.filters.hidden = function( elem ) {
    // Support: Opera <= 12.12
    // Opera reports offsetWidths and offsetHeights less than zero on some elements
    return elem.offsetWidth <= 0 && elem.offsetHeight <= 0;
};
jQuery.expr.filters.visible = function( elem ) {
    return !jQuery.expr.filters.hidden( elem );
};
```